# launching more than one activity in android wear

Tags: wear-os, activity-stack

Can we launch more than one activity in android wear micro app? I mean is it possible to have more than one activity in android wear activity stack?

I tried launching 2 activities, but it threw an out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, it can run more than one activity in wear, it can do many thing as the phone can do
please check your code, oom is your code problem